# MagicalRecord Not saving to-many relationship entity

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2

When I launch my app for the first time, I create `Show` Object which contains has to-many relation ship to `Feature` entity. After launching my app only for the first time, it stores correctly my Show Object with it correct Features. The problem, is when I launch my app a second time, it removes all the features from my database in spite of not accessing DB for a second time (We are update Shows only once every 5 days).

Here the code I use for storage :

```
-(void)insertOrUpdateShow:(Show_fr*)show withObjects:(NSDictionary*)item forMoc:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    if (!show)
    {
        show = [Show_fr MR_createInContext:context];
    }
    show.title                  = [item objectForKey:@"title"] ;
    show.latitude               = [item objectForKey:@"latitude"] ;
    show.longitude              = [item objectForKey:@"longitude"] ;
    NSArray * features          = [item objectForKey:@"feature"] ;
    for (NSDictionary * featureDict in features) {
        [show addFeaturesObject:[self createFeatureFromDictionnary:featureDict forMoc:context]];
    }
    [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
}

-(Feature_fr*)createFeatureFromDictionnary:(NSDictionary*)featureDictionary forMoc:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    Feature_fr * feature = [Feature_fr MR_createInContext:context];
    feature.icon    = [featureDictionary objectForKey:@"icon"] ;
    feature.label   = [featureDictionary objectForKey:@"label"] ;
    feature.value   = [featureDictionary objectForKey:@"value"] ;
    return feature;
}
```

Just To precise that at the first launching I have 6 shows and 127 features object in my DB, and from the second time I have my 6 shows but 0 features.

Would you know please how to resolve this problem ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magical Record Save Block To Know that your data is saved successfully in both tables

```
[[yourObject managedObjectContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
    NSLog(@"Object %@",object);
        }
 }];
```

In this code "yourobject" is Object which you want to save

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for your Answer, My object is saved, I cant see it using an SQlite Browser, the problem, is some how, my objects (features) are deleted from the DB if I relaunch the App.

Comment: My advice is to Install a sqlite client and then check whether features are are inserting to persistent storage

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to set a model.

```
MagicalRecord.setDefaultModelFrom(Model.self)
```